# jQuery: Replace all CSS Background Images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use jQuery to replace all images that are added with the  tag.  How can I also replace all images that are added with CSS?
This is what I have [tried with my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXMv/).So if u see, the jQuery works for img tags but not the h1 tag.

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('src')) $(this).attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif');
    });
    $('h1').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('url')) $(this).attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$('h1').css('background-image', 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif)');
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXMv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly display an image as an attribute of a `h1` tag. If you want to change the image, you might want to change the css value of the h1 tags by calling something like this:

```
$(this).css('background-image', 'transparent url("...")...');
```

Comment: This targets all elements in general, but code should be `'background-image', 'url("...")'` or `'background', 'transparent url("...")...'`

Comment: sorry, this line was just meant to replace the line `$(this).attr('src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif');` from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/5WXMv/4/):

```
 $('*').each(function() {    
        if($(this).css('background-image') !== 'none' ) {
            $(this).css({ 'background-image' : 'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif)' });
        }        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(this).css('background-image',  'url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried it on your fiddle and this is working perfectly,

```
$('h1').filter(function() {
    return ( $(this).css('background-image') !== '');
}).css("background","url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0f/Red_X_Symbol.gif') no-repeat");
```